# Application crash on Lock when Japanese keyboard used

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

The problem appeared on iOS 6. To reproduce it you need to enter text with japanese (kana) keyboard and press on 'Lock' button when suggestions appear. After unlocking user is on application dashboard instead of the application. If press on application icon it's loaded again - app crashed when lock was pressed. It's true even for apple apps like Notes

Crash logs:

```
Application Specific Information:
YOUR_APP was suspended with locked system files: 
/private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/PhraseLearning_ja_JP.db/sqlite.db
/private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/BigramLearning_ja_JP.db/sqlite.db
```

It seems iOS tries to save user's choices in db to make suggestions more intellectual but it writes to db when it cannot write.

I've posted bug to Apple already but nobody know when they fix it

You can's just say to people using your application that it is Apple's problem - you need to solve it. I tried hide keyboard on applicationWillResignActive and show it when app loads but it didn't help a lot. Any suggestions?

UPDATE. I was hoping they will fix it in 6.0.1 but unfortunately NO :-(

Comment: It seems that this issue has been fixed in IOS6.1, but we don't know they fix in which version? 6.02? 6.03? any detail information?? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'Task Completion' to delay enter background.
Hide keyboard during additional time (10 minutes).
It is workaround.

Example:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Acquired additional time
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
        backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
    }

    if (backgroundSupported) {
        backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
            backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];
    }

    // Hide keyboard 
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I think some more code was needed.

If Back -> Fore -> Back in 10 minutes(twice more...),
Then n times backgroundTasks has created.
And "backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTa..." cause leaks previous backgroundTask.

So. before calling "backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTa..."
check "backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid" and call endBackgroundTask: .

How about?

Comment: This seems to work even without resignFirstResponder! All you need to to is begin the background task.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the other answer and its comments, I found that this worked for me. It has the advantage that you don't need to know which text field was active:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];

    backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```